# How to password protect a web directory with oAuth?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, oauth

Is it possible to protect a web directory using oAuth credentials?

i.e rather then using the default `.htaccess` method, replace it where you whitelist an email address and use Google or GitHub e.g. to authenticate.

This is for a small flat file CMS using PHP.